# How to find ngrams in email id?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have requirement to create a custom feature transformer in spark scala.I.For instance i have a scala dataframe

```
+--------------------+ .  
|          email_list| .  
+--------------------+ .  
|testmail1115@gmail.com| .  
|mavenmaven@mlail.com| .  
|dnd.7899334622@gmail.com| .  
+--------------------+ .
```

If i use the transformer it converts the input array of strings into an array of n-grams.like below:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+  
|          email_list|              ngrams| .  
+--------------------+--------------------+   
|testmail1115@gmail.com|[t e, e s, s t, t...|  
|mavenmaven@mlail.com|[m a, a v, v e, e...| .  
|dnd.7899334622@gmail.com|[d n, n d, d...| .  
+--------------------+--------------------+ .
```

How to get the distinct ngram present rather the pattern or array in the below code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.NGram
val emailD1F=emailDF.withColumn("email_split", split(col("email_list"), "@").getItem(0)).withColumn("email_split", split(col("email_split"), "")) .   
val ngram = new NGram().setN(2).setInputCol("col1").setOutputCol("ngrams")

val ngramDataFrame = ngram.transform(emailD1F)
ngramDataFrame.show()
```

Comment: Do youean number of bigrams in each entry in ngram column?

Comment: Yes correct it has to show the number of bigrams in each row.